# How to tell Autotools Build System (Guile 1.8.8) Where Libtool is Installed?

Tags: gnu, autotools

I am trying to build Guile 1.8.8 from source. I am stuck at the point where the build system is looking for `libtool`. I have installed it in a non-standard location.

I have already built Guile 2.0.11. In 2.0.11 build system, there is an explicit flag to configure `--with-libltdl-prefix`, which I think tells the build system where libtool is installed.

For Guile 1.8.8, I have Libtool installed in a non-standard location. How do I tell the build system where it is installed?

I am specifically getting error messages like:

```
libguile/Makefile.am:40: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined
libguile/Makefile.am:40:   The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `LT_INIT'
```

I think in general this is a question regarding one or more of the autotools and how the build system finds programs / headers / libraries in non-standard locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is informative: [How to point autoconf/automake to non-standard packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429896/how-to-point-autoconf-automake-to-non-standard-packages)

---

1. Find the directory where *.m4 exists, which corresponds to libtool, or package which is in non-standard location.
2. export ACLOCAL_PATH=/path/to/m4/file
3. cd /path/to/configure.[in,ac]
4. autoreconf -if
5. ./configure